# Laravel 5.6 not saving field in `created` model event

Tags: php, laravel, events, orm, eloquent

I am trying to save a field from the `created` model event but for some reason the `stripe_coupon_id` column is never being saved. The `created` event does run as I've tested by trying a `dd` inside it and it does fire the event but just does not save that column.

```
class DiscountRate extends Model
{
    public $table = "discount_rates";

    public $primaryKey = "id";

    public $timestamps = true;

    public $fillable = [
        'id',
        'name',
        'rate',
        'active',
        'stripe_coupon_id'
    ];



    public static function boot()
        {
            parent::boot();
            self::created(function ($discountRate) {
                $coupon_id = str_slug($discountRate->name);
                $discountRate->stripe_coupon_id = $coupon_id;
            });

        }
}
```

In my controller I simply call a service function which calls the default Laravel model create function:

```
public function store(DiscountRateCreateRequest $request)
    {
        $result = $this->service->create($request->except('_token'));

        if ($result) {
            return redirect(route('discount_rates.edit', ['id' => $result->id]))->with('message', 'Successfully created');
        }

    }
```

`discount_rates` table:

[image]

Comment: did you tried $discountRate->save() after set it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `created` event is triggered after your model is created. In this case, you need to to call `$discountRate->save()` in the end in order to update the model which you just created.

As alternative, you can use `creating` event instead. In this case you don't need to call `save()` in the end because the model is not yet saved in your database. 
A big difference in `creating` event is that the model does not have an id yet if you use auto-incrementing which is default behavior.

More info about events you can find [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#events).

Answer (score 0):

you have to set `stripe_coupon_id` before creating. So replace `static::creating` instead of `self::created` in `boot` method of `DiscountRate` model.

Comment: Why do you have to set `stripe_coupon_id` before creating? It's not a required attribute? `creating` and `created` both happen at different times. I want to use the `created` event so that my code only runs once the record has been successfully created not whilst it is `creating`.